# Return with different ResponseDTO according querystring parameter value in Servicestack?

Tags: servicestack

I want to return different type of response according `QueryString parameter` value. Example

```
http://localhost:8080/myservice?Type=low --> return responseType1
http://localhost:8080/myservice?Type=high --> return responseType2
```

according Type value in URL, I want to different type of response in service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly discouraged to change the return type based on how you call the Service.  Your clients bind to the response of your Service -- changing it indiscriminately based on some runtime heuristic will break them.

But if you must, ServiceStack Services doesn't enforce a strict response type and lets you return any `object`, e.g:

```
public object Any(Request request)
{
    return request.Type == "low"
       ? responseType1
       : responseType2;
}
```

It does mean the Request DTO can no longer have a consistent `IReturn<Response>` interface marker and you'll now force the clients to know which Response is returned and when, which they'll have to maintain themselves on the call-site, e.g:

```
var response = client.Get<ResponseType>(new Request { Type = "low" });
```

This also affects metadata services which can't rely on the Service to have a consistent Response Type.

Comment: Below thing can be possible? http://localhost:8080/myservice?Type1=low --> `return responseType1`
        http://localhost:8080/myservice?Type2=high --> `return responseType2` Here I have changed the parameter means that i have change RequestDTO in both case.